# Best way to use RegEx on large text

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

I have a text column that contains plain text from PDF, word, excel, etc. Searching for phrases using SQL works great.

The user wants to see excerpts of text that contain the search phrase before opening file. Since SQL doesn't return where the phrase is in the column, I decided to use a regex to find and show it.

When the text is large **27 MB** CPU jumps to close to 100% and is slow to do the job. The regex pattern retrieves 5 words before and after the search term.

Here is the code:

```
 HashSet<string> str = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (string sPhrase in searchArr)
            {
                string sPattern;
                if (sPhrase.Contains("*"))
                    sPattern = sPhrase.Replace("*", @"\w*");
                else
                    sPattern = sPhrase;

                string pattern = "(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}" + sPattern + "(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}";
                Debug.Write(string.Format("Pattern:{0}\n\r",pattern));

                Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                Match match = reg.Match(Text);

                while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
                {
                    string s = match.Value;
                    if (s.Contains("\n\r"))
                        s = s.Replace("\n\r", " ");

                    s = s.Replace("\n", " ");
                    s = s.Replace("\r", " ");

                    //Checks for dups
                    if (!str.Contains(s))
                    {
                        str.Add(s);
                        AttachmentSearchResult r = new AttachmentSearchResult(s);

                        yield return r;
                    }

                    match = match.NextMatch();
                }
            }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way other than retrieving all the text in memory and searching that? Or can SQL 2005 accomplish what I'm trying to do?
Thanks

Comment: You definitely *don't* want to be doing string operations on a 27 MB string.

Comment: Have you profiled the application to know which part of the above method is the most expensive?

Comment: NextMatch and Match(Text) are the most expensive

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of to do this is to use a dedicated search engine.  I've used [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/lucene.net.html) before to do something similar, and it was relatively straightforward.  You might also want to look into [SimpleLucene](http://simplelucene.codeplex.com/) to make your life easier.

However, adding an entirely new search engine is going to require a time investment which may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your requirement can be solved with this but you can create a SQL expression column with a regular expression in it ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)). This way you can pass the parsing duty to SQL server.